# Error: more than one device/emulator when using adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, mobile, adb

I switched from using USB to using Wifi for ADB, but when I successfully build I get the following error: `Error: more than one device/emulator`.

I think this also causes the react native asset build to fail. I checked all of the devices connected using `adb devices` and I only see one:

[image]

What I tried to do is adb kill-server and start-server, run this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`, but nothing has worked so far.

Another note, I followed this SO answer to connect ADB with wifi:

[How can I use adb over WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364380/how-can-i-use-adb-over-wifi)

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: Did you restart the computer? :D

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Not yet...

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Ok I did and the problem is still occurring.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @thxmxx No, I have not yet...

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Looks like bug in adb. My version is: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.1-6435776
Have you found solution or any workaround?