# ADB failing to connect to the ip address

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, networking, adb

It's odd that this is happening because it was just working a couple of weeks before Christmas and starting it back up in January 2019 it does not want to work. I didn't do anything to my network, no updates, followed the correct steps here: [How can I use adb over WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364380/how-can-i-use-adb-over-wifi)

I don't know what's going on. Is there a way I can, I guess, find a network bug in the CMD? One of the new things I did try was ping my phone's ip and it said it received and sent pings. I also did `adb reconnect offline`. That didn't do anything as well.

Is there anything else I can try?

Details: **Phone - Note 8 (non- rooted)**, **Computer - Windows 10 laptop**

Comment: "failing to connect" is very vague.

Comment: The phone's IP address may change over the time when it receives it's IP address via DHCP. Recheck the phone for the IP it has in your Wifi network.

Comment: @TheWanderer I mean all it says in the Command Prompt is 'failed to connect to ip address'.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I checked many times in the Wifi Settings and I also downloaded an app that tells me my ip on the phone. It's the same ip as the one I used before this month.