# How to connect to a ADB device over Internet(not wifi)?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb

Sorry but I have been searching this from last two days but found no answer.
What I am trying to do is connect to a ADB device over internet which is far away from me.
We are team of two people and I want my colleague to run the app on my emulator or my phone. But she is unable to do that. I tried connecting over TCP but I think only devices on same network can connect with TCP.
Any help will be appreciated! Thank You!!

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364380/how-can-i-use-adb-over-wifi

Comment: Also please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: Does this help - [how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429/how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment)

Comment: Thanks @Debendra for your efforts, I have read that but it won't help me because the ADB device is not connected to a local wifi. If you got something else I would love to know that.

Comment: Thanks @Nitish, I think your provided link can help me. I will definitely give a shot to this!!

Comment: ADB over IP uses unencrypted and unprotected communication. Therefore it should only be used in a secure network and never through the internet. If you want to connect to a remote device use at least a VPN or SSH port forwarding to establish a secure connection to the target network the device is in!

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the solution which solves the same problem,

They call it AstroFarm, its used to share the devices over the internet for development, manual QA or automation or DevOps in CICD pipeline as well.

https://techblogs.42gears.com/how-we-solved-the-challenge-of-remotely-providing-devices-for-devops-employee-onboarding-and-customer-support/

But looks like this tool is paid one.